# htaccess redirect multiple query strings (no matter WHAT order they appear in)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

So I've got a website that has old query string urls.  The issue though is there are multiple versions of these query strings indexed in Google and being crawled on the site. They are going to be redirected to a new SEF url.

SO, currently I have this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mls/property.cfm [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mlsid=(.*)&wsid=(.*)&mlsnumber=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) /mls-redirects.cfm?mlsid=%1&wsid=%2&mlsnumber=%3 [QSA,L]
```

Where mls-redirects.cfm is doing the redirecting.  So this handles when the url (and works great!) has the query string in the ORDER of MLSID, WSID and MLSNUMBER.  But this does NOT work if WSID comes first, or last. Etc etc.

Rather than using all different iterations of code, is there a way to not make this "Order of Query String Sensitive"? HA!

Appreciate all the help!

EDIT: Also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mls/property.cfm [NC]  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mlsid=(.*)  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} wsid=(.*)  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mlsnumber=(.*)  
RewriteRule (.*) /mls-redirects.cfm?mlsid=%1&wsid=%2&mlsnumber=%3 [R=301,L]
```

Like so?  this results in the following URL:  `/mls-redirects.cfm?mlsid=86278683&wsid=&mlsnumber=`

I feel like we are close though!

Comment: Have you tried removing the `^` from `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mlsid=(.*)&wsid=(.*)&mlsnumber=(.*)` and then putting each `RewriteCond` for each query string directive on its own line? Example: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mlsid=(.*)`

Comment: Apologies for the formatting. Edited above.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mls/property.cfm [NC]  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mlsid=(.*)  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} wsid=(.*)  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mlsnumber=(.*)  
RewriteRule (.*) /mls-redirects.cfm?mlsid=%1&wsid=%2&mlsnumber=%3 [R=301,L]  

Like so?  this results in the following URL:  /mls-redirects.cfm?mlsid=86278683&wsid=&mlsnumber=     

I feel like we are close though!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (or at least help get you on the right track):

```
## Set "a" as an empty environmental variable
RewriteRule ^ - [E=a]
## Set "b" as an empty environmental variable
RewriteRule ^ - [E=b]
## Set "c" as an empty environmental variable
RewriteRule ^ - [E=c]

## If there's a key of "mlsid" in the query string,
## assign its value to "a"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mlsid=([^&$]+)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=a:%1]

## If there's a key of "wsid" in the query string,
## assign its value to "b"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} wsid=([^&$]+)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=b:%1]

## If there's a key of "mlsnumber" in the query string,
## assign its value to "c"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mlsnumber=([^&$]+)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=c:%1]

## Final checks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mls/property.cfm [NC]

## At least one of our variables needs a non-empty value
## (remove [OR] from each line to require the variables to have a value)
RewriteCond %{ENV:a} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:b} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:c} !^$

## You could also delete the above three lines and
## uncomment the next line instead
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (mlsid|wsid|mlsnumber)(=)(.*)

RewriteRule (.*) /mls-redirects.cfm?mlsid=%{ENV:a}&wsid=%{ENV:b}&mlsnumber=%{ENV:c} [L,R=302]
```

Hope that helps.